# Python operator asterisk in list

Tags: python

Why the output here is [[2, 1], [**2**, 1]] and not [[2,1],[***1***,1]]

```
a = [[1] * 2] * 2
a[0][0]=2
print (a)
```

I have done quite research on the * operator in list but it doesn't seem to get me to the correct understanding

Comment: Also tried 
a = [[1] * 3] * 3
a[0][0]=3
print (a)

[[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1]] 
shouldn't it only change the first element in the first list

Comment: Because `a[0]` is same with `a[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the fact, how Python handles objects in memory. When you are using the `* 2` to duplicate the list, Python does not create a separate list object in memory, it only copies the memory pointer for the second list position. Due to this behaviour when you mutate the first element, it affects the second too.
You can use the `id()` function to check the object ids within Python. You will see that `a[0]` and `a[1]` will have the same ids.

```
>>> a = [[1] * 2] * 2
>>> a[0][0] = 2
>>> a
[[2, 1], [2, 1]]
>>> id(a[0])
140608840898432
>>> id(a[1])
140608840898432
>>> id(a[0]) == id(a[1])
True
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do this, you are just creating copies of list, n times.

So the inner lists here are actually the same list. When you modify the first one, you're also modifying the second. If you don't want that functionality, you can do this instead:

```
a = [[1 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]
```

Comment: what about the anonymous inner list [1] it's also copied but not impacted should all the values be [[2,2],[2,2]] ?

Comment: See the comment in @iamnifer's post.